# Change value of an item in array each time it occurs PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am a beginner with PHP. I want to upload a csv file and create an array. Within that array I wish to change the value of a certain key.

For example the query key:
From
`[query] => https://www.example.com/search/output/person/?loc=%5B%22105490917%22%2C%22101452733%22%5D&keywords=Computational%20Biologist&origin=host`

To
`[query] => Computational Biologist`

As the `&keywords=` and `&origin=` are consistent I have tried using a mix of `strstr`, `str_replace` and `substr` these work when a single variable is set with the above data but not when the data is part of an array.

Can anyone help to remove the unwanted data each time it appears in the array?

The data from the csv file i am trying to upload, change and put into an array

```
query,firstName,lastName,
https://www.example.com/search/output/person/?loc=%5B%22105490917%22%2C%22101452733%22%5D&keywords=Computational%20Biologist&origin=host,John,Smith,
https://www.example.com/search/output/person/?loc=%5B%22105490917%22%2C%22101452733%22%5D&keywords=Computational%20Biologist&origin=host,fred,clause,
https://www.example.com/search/output/person/?loc=%5B%22105490917%22%2C%22101452733%22%5D&keywords=Computational%20Biologist&origin=host,brendan,bobby,
```

My code so far:

```php
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='post'>
        
<label>Upload  CSV file Here</label><br>
 
<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'>
</br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload File'>
 
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $file = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    $all_rows = array();
    $header = fgetcsv($file);
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
        $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row); 
    }
}
        
echo "<pre>";
print_r($all_rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

I want to be left with an array the looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => Computational Biologist
            [firstName] => John
            [lastName] => Smith
            [] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => Computational Biologist
            [firstName] => fred
            [lastName] => clause
            [] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [query] => Computational Biologist
            [firstName] => brendan
            [lastName] => bobby
            [] => 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using the below:

```
foreach($all_rows as $key => $value)
{
  $all_rows[$key]['query'] = strstr($all_rows[$key]['query'], 'keywords=');

    $all_rows[$key]['query'] = str_replace('keywords=', '',$all_rows[$key]['query']);
    $all_rows[$key]['query'] = substr($all_rows[$key]['query'], 0, strpos($all_rows[$key]['query'], "&"));
    $all_rows[$key]['query']= urldecode($all_rows[$key]['query']);
}
```